# Message: Call to undefined method CI_Input::manufacturer()

Tags: codeigniter

can somebody tell me what's wrong with this code? This is located in my controller. I have an error message "Message: Call to undefined method CI_Input::manufacturer()"

```
public function edit_manufacturer(){
  $this->load->helper("security");
  $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  if($this->input->manufacturer('submit')){
    $manufacturer_name = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->manufacturer('manufacturer_name'));
    $this->asset_model->edit_manufacturer($manufacturer_id, $manufacturer_name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a reserved class from CodeIgniter and the methods are the following

```
$this->input->post();
$this->input->get();
$this->input->cookie();
$this->input->server();
```

therefore, manufacturer method doesn't exist unless you modified this class and created the method.

Maybe what you want to do is:

```
$this->input->post('manufacturer');
```

or

```
$this->input->post('submit');
```

For more information visit [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) Documentation